# Подгрузка данных с внешний ресурсов на GitHub

Tags: github

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема. Выложила сайт на гитхаб, после обнаружила проблему с подключением карты и шрифтов http://take.ms/JZ3fh . С чем это может быть связано? Заранее огромное человеческое спасибо.

Comment: Вы выложили сайт на Github вот так http://vasilukwolf.github.io/All-Color-Converter/. Если да, то, то скиньте ссылку пожалуйста. Но судя по всему вам непроходимо подключить через https

Comment: Пожалуйста, вот ссылка на сайт https://a-kolesnikova.github.io/

Comment: Вроде бы я был прав https://vasilukwolf.github.io/a-kolesnikova.github.io/.Сделал запрос на github.

Comment: По поводу ключа https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key. Я так понял его нужно получить и вставить ключ от google.

Comment: Хорошо я все поняла) Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#client-id

Comment: Это для получения  ключа

Comment: https://vasilukwolf.github.io/a-kolesnikova.github.io/

Comment: Я сделал запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить эти строчки кода

https://github.com/a-kolesnikova/a-kolesnikova.github.io/compare/master...vasilukwolf:gh-pages

Получить ключ для API карты

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#client-id

Comment: Спасибо, я все выполнила. Подскажите пожалуйста, а в чем может быть проблема на вот этой странице https://a-kolesnikova.github.io/portfolio/magic/contacts.html http://take.ms/oPGXU ? Что я изначально, при загрузке сайта на GitHub, не правильно выполнила, что повлекло такие ошибки?

Comment: По мне так все хорошо, но все так front-end нужно выкладывать отдельно в ветку gh-pages(лучшая практика). Подробнее это в документации https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/. Плюс вы не указали браузер, в котором крокозябит. Из ошибок вы пропустили  ссылку логотипа. Если вы имеете ввиду php, то думаю он будет обрабатывать его только с другого сервера.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо)